# Date/time multi-row conversion problem in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing around with a tallying program that allows me to export data to csv.  The problem I'm having is that the data is supplied in a format that I don't know how to convert into a normal date-time format for doing analyses upon.

The input file provides data in the following form after loading with pandas' read_csv:

```
index   data            count 
1       11/15/20        nan   
2       16:43:23.2411   1     
3       11/14/20        nan   
4       18:53:33.124    1     
5       4:33:12.451     -1    
6       1:18:53.121     1
```

Can someone help me with rearranging the data to be in a more traditional date-time format, e.g.:

```
index   datetime                     count 
1       11/15/20 16:43:23.2411       1   
2       11/14/20 18:53:33.124        1
3       11/14/20 4:33:12.451         -1
4       11/14/20 1:18:53.121         1
```

The only thing I found that I thought would be helpful was the pandas unstack function, but that didn't work as intended.

```
data_timestamps = pd.read_csv("load_datetime.csv") 
t = data_timestamps.unstack(level=0)
```

Perhaps I'm not using it correctly.  Nonetheless, any ideas on how to best convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the job up, note that `count` is a function so avoiding that name is a good thing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
datain = { 'index' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'data': ['11/15/20', '16:43:23.2411', '11/14/20 ', '18:53:33.124', '4:33:12.451', '1:18:53.121'], 'value' : [np.nan, 1,np.nan, 1 , -1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(datain)
```

that gives us

```
    index   data            value
0   1       11/15/20        NaN
1   2       16:43:23.2411   1.0
2   3       11/14/20        NaN
3   4       18:53:33.124    1.0
4   5       4:33:12.451     -1.0
5   6       1:18:53.121     1.0
```

do the work

```
df['date'] = np.where(df['value'].shift(1).isna(), df.data.shift(1), None)
df['date'] = df['date'].ffill()
df= df[~(df['value'].isna())]
```

So fill in the values with the previous value of data when the Nan occours
Then fill forward the date
Then remove everything that has a value row of NaN
Giving us

```
        index   data            value   date
1       2       16:43:23.2411   1.0     11/15/20
3       4       18:53:33.124    1.0     11/14/20
4       5       4:33:12.451     -1.0    11/14/20
5       6       1:18:53.121     1.0     11/14/20
```

All you need to do is combine date and data and put it to a date time.